# PHP - Session can't store classes?

Tags: php, session

**Complete example:**
**A) What it's expected to happen.**
It's expected to save data in a `$_SESSION["user_data"]` variable. It means that if I do `print $_SESSION["user_data"]->getUUID();` it must print the user UUID because it's defined in here: `$_SESSION["user_data"] = UserRep::selectUser(Conn::getConnection(), $token);`

**B) What actually happens.**
It actually returns the next error:

> Fatal error: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "UserMan" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in C:\xampp\htdocs\esotic1jdv\index.php on line 67

Note: The line 67 is `<?php echo $_SESSION["user_data"]->getUUID(); ?>`

But the following code does work:
`$data = UserRep::selectUser(Conn::getConnection(), $token);`
and then
`print $data->getUUID();`

**C) An example of what I want to happen.**

```
<?php
 print $_SESSION["user_data"]->getUUID();
```

Must give as result:

> 569047265eca48a8aa34847a3a059a7ea8170dc3

**D) What actually happens.**
    getUUID();
Give as result:

> Fatal error: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "UserMan" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in C:\xampp\htdocs\esotic1jdv\index.php on line 67

Comment: Please stop adding objects to the session. It's a maintenance / debugging nightmare at best and a security vulnerability waiting to happen at worst.

Comment: What may I do then @PeeHaa ? Save just the UUID and then get the data by it?

Comment: I'd second PeeHaa's comment: the less in the session, the better. And yes, storing the UUID and then getting user from database is better. If you're worried about speed, then many database have cache, alternatively (my preferred) is to self-serialize the critical parts of the object that allow you to recreate it and recreate from cache (if available) and fallback to DB (if not available in cache).

Comment: It's a good practice, thanks to both of you! And... I know it's a little bit off-topic, but where may I learn about cyber security? (I have every single data encrypted, but I need to know if it's really sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ensure that the class definition is loaded before you session_start(), otherwise a default class (with no methods) is created instead.

Auto-loading classes wont work. Nor will loading class definitions AFTER session_start.

Comment: Thanks! Solved... I can't believe that I forgot to include the file before start the session...